# MySQL C API. Problem with retrieving information from the table SOLUTION

Tags: mysql, c, api

I have a display_menu function that makes different queries according to the given parameter. This function has to call a function that must print out selected info. However, that doesn't happen, the value of row is always NULL but if I move the whole print_row function into the body of display_menu it works just fine. Could you tell me what causes this problem and how can I solve it?

My mistake here is silly. I forgot to add '!' before calling mysql_query(). Thanks to @Strom in comments for noticing it.

**But then I got another problem**: when I tried to INSERT some information INTO the table with a special function I implemented it went good. **BUT** when I tried to display what I've just added with display_menu it didn't appear. The problem was in the way I read those types. I read it with fgets(), but fgets() reads newline character as well so when I made these queries that are represented in code I didn't take into account '\n' that was stored in my dish table after the 'type' string. I just changed fgets() to scanf(), cause scanf() does not read newline character.

Hope it might be helpful for someone :)

```
    void display_menu(MYSQL* connect, int type)
 {
    if(type == snack || type == all){
        printf("*********************************** Snacks ******************************\n");
        if(!mysql_query(connect, "SELECT name, price FROM dish WHERE type = 'snack'"))
            print_rows(connect);
    }
    if(type == first || type == all){
        printf("******************************* First courses ***************************\n");
        if(mysql_query(connect, "SELECT name, price FROM dish WHERE type = 'first'"))
            print_rows(connect);
    }
    if(type == main_dish || type == all){
        printf("******************************** Main dishes ****************************\n");
        if(mysql_query(connect, "SELECT name, price FROM dish WHERE type = 'main'"))
            print_rows(connect);
    }
    if(type == dessert || type == all){
        printf("********************************** Desserts *****************************\n");
        if(mysql_query(connect, "SELECT name, price FROM dish WHERE type = 'dessert'"))
            print_rows(connect);
    }
    if(type == drink || type == all){
        printf("*********************************** Drinks ******************************\n");
        if(mysql_query(connect, "SELECT name, price FROM dish WHERE type = 'drink'"))
            print_rows(connect);
    printf("**************************************************************************\n");
    }
}

    /*
This functions prints out all the selected rows
 */
 void print_rows(MYSQL* connect)
 {
    result = mysql_store_result(connect);
    while((row = mysql_fetch_row(result))){
        printf("%s ", row[0] );
        printf("– %s czk\n", row[1]);
    }
    mysql_free_result(result);
 }
```

Comment: Are you sure that `print_rows` gets called at all? Because looking at [mysql_query](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-query.html) manual, it should return -> Zero for success. Nonzero if an error occurred.

Comment: Oh... Such a silly mistake, thank you very much. But now I have another problem...

Comment: Edit your question or open a new one if it is too far from the original problem.